# DirectAdmin Installation on FreeBSD

Tags: gcc, bind, freebsd, directadmin

I want to install DA and it requires both bind and gcc to be installed first, but they aren't installed on my machine. How do I install bind and gcc on FreeBSD 10.0?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install them from packages or ports. (I'm assuming you installed the ports tree when you installed the OS; it is generally a good idea to do so unless you are severely restricted in free disk space.)

If you *don't* want to modify the port's options, you can use pre-compiled packages; it's usually faster.

Note that all commands prefixed by `#` need to be run as `root`.

FreeBSD comes with a `make` program, but a lot of Linux software assumes you have GNU make. You you might want to install that as well.

For bind:

```
# pkg search bind
bind-tools-9.10.2
bind910-9.10.2_2
bind99-9.9.7_2
bindgraph-0.2_7
bindtest-1.56_1
cbind-6
hs-zlib-bindings-0.1.1.3_7
kdebindings-4.14.3
keybinder-0.3.0_3
keybinder-gtk3-0.3.0
libbind-6.0_1
luabind-0.9.1_2
p5-BIND-Conf_Parser-0.95_1
p5-BIND-Config-Parser-0.01_1
p5-Catalyst-Controller-BindLex-0.03_1
p5-Data-Bind-0.30_2
p5-Regexp-Bind-0.05_1
p5-Text-Bind-0.04_1
redland-bindings-1.0.17.1_1
rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.12
rubygem-bindata-2.1.0
socketbind-1
vbindiff-3.0.b4
xapian-bindings-1.2.20
xbindkeys-1.8.6_2

# pkg install bind910-9.10.2_2
# pkg install bind-tools-9.10.2
```

And for gcc:

```
# pkg search gcc
amd64-gcc-4.9.1_1
amd64-xtoolchain-gcc-0.1
arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.9.1_2
avr-gcc-4.8.3_1
avr-gcc-devel-4.10.0.s20140803
colorgcc-1.3.2
gcc-4.8.4_1
gcc-arm-embedded-4.9.20141203_2
gcc-aux-20141023_1
gcc-ecj-4.5
gcc46-4.6.4_5,1
gcc47-4.7.4_3,1
gcc47-aux-20140612_1
gcc48-4.8.5.s20150402
gcc49-4.9.3.s20150325
gcc5-5.0.s20150405
gcc5-aux-20150405
gccmakedep-1.0.2_1
mingw32-gcc-4.8.1,1
msp430-gcc-4.6.3.20120406_3,2
powerpc64-gcc-4.9.1_1
powerpc64-xtoolchain-gcc-0.1
psptoolchain-gcc-stage1-4.6.2_3
psptoolchain-gcc-stage2-4.6.2_3
sparc64-gcc-4.9.1_1
sparc64-xtoolchain-gcc-0.1
tigcc-0.96.b8_3
zpu-gcc-1.0

# pkg install gcc-4.8.4_1
```

For GNU make;

```
# pkg search gmake
gmake-4.1_1
gmake-lite-4.1_1

# pkg install gmake-4.1_1
```

If you want to use non-standard options (e.g. if you want to have java support in gcc), you'll have to compile the port yourself.

For ports;

```
# cd /usr/ports/lang/gcc
# make install clean
```

and

```
# cd /usr/ports/dns/bind910
# make install clean
# cd /usr/ports/dns/bind-tools
# make install clean
```

GNU make doesn't have options, so just use the package.

*UPDATE*:

The DirectAdmin site refers to FreeBSD's superceded packaging tools in some places. Use `pkg install` instead of `pkg_add`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use official DirectAdmin instructions for pre-install software which may be found at:

https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=354

It will provide copy-paste box with all required software packages to be installed using your OS package manager.